# Cordova / Phonegap All External Ajax Requests Returns 404

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I did have a Cordova 3.3 app, but yesterday i update the cordova and all my app plugins to v5.0 of apache cordova.

Since i did it, i put a splash screen plugin and build my app without problems, but when i tried to test, i saw that all external ajax requests returns a **404 error**, including a simple ajax request to google.

---

**Everything works fine on any browser.**

---

My config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />

<platform name="android">
    <splash src="screen/android/ldpi.9.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <splash src="screen/android/mdpi.9.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <splash src="screen/android/hdpi.9.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <splash src="screen/android/xhdpi.9.png" density="xhdpi"/>
</platform>

<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
<preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
<preference name="monaca:DisableCookie" value="false"/>
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
</feature>
<preference name="monaca:androidVersionCode" value="1"/>
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true"/>
<preference name="monaca:MonacaBackendUrl" value="https://cloud.monaca.mobi/json-rpc/"/>
<preference name="monaca:MonacaBackendId" value="5462a7b9fd1734575d0f0317"/>
<preference name="monaca:MonacaBackendApiKey" value="e839514dc867719689001fa1c32a17136adeb1ba631c5885b2f996b1375f9cb4"/>
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
<preference name="monaca:AndroidIsPackageNameSeparate" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="monaca:WebViewEngine" value="default"/>
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff1b3c81"/>

<access origin="*"/>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.nowa" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="Nowa" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

A example of ajax request that doesn't work:

```
$.ajax( "http://www.google.com.br" )
        .done(function() {
            alert( "success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );
        });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cordova 5.0 blocks external http requests by default.

Try adding [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to your project.

Comment: Worked for me too. I love you.