# phonegap 5.2 ajax calls throwing 404 recently

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I had a code that was working fine in my local and phonegap build untill a week back.
Now All my internet calls have started to fail. ajax to start with. I am getting a response of 404.

I have seen below links and lot more that are similar to them. Just adding of plugin and `access-origin = "*"` seem to be solving their problem.
I had the plugin earlier as well and now I added source and version additionally to the plugin to try.

My guess is I am missing something minor or basic here my code. Phonegap build I am using is 5.2

URLs for reference : 
[Cordova / Phonegap All External Ajax Requests Returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014539/cordova-phonegap-all-external-ajax-requests-returns-404)
[Phonegap Build .ajax request returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233919/phonegap-build-ajax-request-returning-404)

manifest has below lines :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"  source="npm" version="1.1.0" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

ajax call code :

```
var url_built_for_ip = "http://abc.xyz.com/whatsMyName/abc";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
alert("state changed "+xmlhttp.status)
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url_built_for_ip,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

NOTE : When I run the same code from my phonegap app, it runs fine (ajax calls work fine.)
    This might look like a duplicate question but it is not, as I have refered the other questions that are providing a solution to similar pronblem, it's just that those solutions are not working for me.

Thank you for your support !!!

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue and i did a few things to fix it, not sure which fixed it.

- ran `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist`
- ran `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@latest`
- ran `cordova prepare android`
- deleted the app from the android phone
- ran `cordova run android --device`

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because the whitelist blocks external calls on default

add this plugin, if is not added yet

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

And add this meta tag to your html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```